# ul and li issues that aren't working well

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Hopefully someone can help me with this, I don't understand how stackoverflow code thing works so I am going to put it in pastebin. (might be messy...)

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
 
 
.nav{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
   
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
   
}
 
.box {
    height:250px;
    background-color:#7289da;
}
 
.boxed {
    height:500px;
    background-color:#314381;
   
}
 
li {
    line-height: 1.7em;
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
   
}
 
.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #292c2f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal 16px sans-serif;
 
    padding: 45px 50px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-left p{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
}
 
/* Footer links */
 
.footer-distributed p.footer-links{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
 
.footer-distributed p.footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 6px;
    max-width: 180px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-right a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;
 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
 
    margin-left: 3px;
}
 
.button {
  border-color:aliceblue;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 260px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
 
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
 
.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
 
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
 
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
 
.bottom-bar {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:.8em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
    padding:15px 0;
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .parallax {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("images/img.jpg");
      /* Set a specific height */
      min-height: 850px;
 
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }
 
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>
 
<body><br>
  <center><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/logo1.png"></a></center>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="servers" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Servers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://discord.gg/aYyYPWh" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Discord</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://arkinator.freshdesk.com/support/home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Help Desk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Vote</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="parallax" style="color:white;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;font-size:50px;text-align:center;"><br><br><br><br><br><b>WELCOME TO ARKINATOR</b><br>
    <center>
      <font style="font-size:20px;display:flex;justify-content: center;"><i>Spears? Check. Bows? Check. Dinos? Check.</i></font>
    </center>
  </div>
 
  <div class="box">
    <br><br>
    <center>
      <font style="color:white;font-size:30px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;"><b>Join Our Discord</b></font>
    </center>
    <center><button class="button"><span><a href="https://discord.gg/aYyYPWh" style="text-decoration:none">Open Discord</a></span></button></center>
  </div>
 
  <div class="boxed">
    <br><br>
    <center>
      <font style="color:white;font-size:30px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;"><b>Want to support ARKinator?</b></font>
    </center>
    <center>
      <font style="color:white;font-size:25px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Benefits from supporting</font>
    </center>
 
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
     
        <li><span class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:white;"></span>
          <font style="color:white;font-size:20px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Discord Donator Rank</font>
        </li>
     
   
        <li><span class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:white;"></span>
          <font style="color:white;font-size:20px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Donator Channel & Room Access</font>
        </li>
     
        <li><span class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:white;"></span>
          <font style="color:white;font-size:20px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Our Appreciation</font>
        </li>
     
    </ul>
    <br><br>
    <font color="white">
        <center>
            Disclaimer: Please note that this is to help us support the server costs. Donating to ARKinator is greatly appreciated however once donated. Non-refundable purchase.
        </center>
            </font>
       
    <br><br>
    <center><button class="button"><span><a href="paypal.me/gamingasylum038" style="text-decoration:none">PayPal</a></span></button></center>
 
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar" style="color:white;">
    Copyright 2018 © ARKinator | All Rights Reserved.
  </div>
</body>
```

So the thing I am trying to do is trying to get my ul code to center every content inside it and my li's to be left aligned so it's nice and neat in 1 line.

Comment: The stack overflow code snippet tool is really powerful. Or you can use jsfiddle to also show your code in action

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, you are saying that you want the content inside the `ul` to be centered, but you want the `li`s to be left aligned. `li`s are the only direct descendant of `ul` elements so you can either have the `li` elements aligned left or center but not both. I hope that makes sense. Please clarify what you are saying, thanks : )

Comment: Pliss do not bypass SO validation by spliting your links, they are there for a reason. Its preferred if you learn to use the tools SO provides.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you want for the end result

Comment: Sorry. Basically i want it to look like this: 
https://gyazo.com/59e41b4b2cbc45bc580e8ab28c8bd3ab

Instead of 
https://gyazo.com/511917854cea077a2e992511c963d7cf

Comment: I just have no idea why it's not working. I have tried 3 different things and running out of ideas @GerardoBLANCO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont get what type of layout you are using. But here is a hotfix for your question.

I added a class to you `ul`, modified ur `li` styles and added some styles to the ul.

Hope this helps

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
 
 
.nav{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
   
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
   
}
 
.box {
    height:250px;
    background-color:#7289da;
}
 
.boxed {
    height:500px;
    background-color:#314381;
   
}
 

.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #292c2f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal 16px sans-serif;
 
    padding: 45px 50px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-left p{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
}
 
/* Footer links */
 
.footer-distributed p.footer-links{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
 
.footer-distributed p.footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 6px;
    max-width: 180px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-right a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;
 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
 
    margin-left: 3px;
}
 
.button {
  border-color:aliceblue;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 260px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
 
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
 
.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
 
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
 
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
 
.bottom-bar {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:.8em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
    padding:15px 0;
  }
  
  
.list-center{
      list-style-type: none;
    display: table;
    margin: 10px auto;
}  


li {
    line-height: 1.7em;
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;

   
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .parallax {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("images/img.jpg");
      /* Set a specific height */
      min-height: 850px;
 
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }
 
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>
 
<body><br>
  <center><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/logo1.png"></a></center>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="servers" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Servers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://discord.gg/aYyYPWh" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Discord</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://arkinator.freshdesk.com/support/home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Help Desk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-border-white w3-bottombar w3-hover-border-blue w3-hover-text-blue">Vote</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="parallax" style="color:white;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;font-size:50px;text-align:center;"><br><br><br><br><br><b>WELCOME TO ARKINATOR</b><br>
    <center>
      <font style="font-size:20px;display:flex;justify-content: center;"><i>Spears? Check. Bows? Check. Dinos? Check.</i></font>
    </center>
  </div>
 
  <div class="box">
    <br><br>
    <center>
      <font style="color:white;font-size:30px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;"><b>Join Our Discord</b></font>
    </center>
    <center><button class="button"><span><a href="https://discord.gg/aYyYPWh" style="text-decoration:none">Open Discord</a></span></button></center>
  </div>
 
  <div class="boxed">
    <br><br>
    <center>
      <font style="color:white;font-size:30px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;"><b>Want to support ARKinator?</b></font>
    </center>
    <center>
      <font style="color:white;font-size:25px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Benefits from supporting</font>
    </center>
 
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;" class="list-center">
     
        <li><span class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:white;"></span>
          <font style="color:white;font-size:20px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Discord Donator Rank</font>
        </li>
     
   
        <li><span class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:white;"></span>
          <font style="color:white;font-size:20px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Donator Channel & Room Access</font>
        </li>
     
        <li><span class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:white;"></span>
          <font style="color:white;font-size:20px;font-family:Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">Our Appreciation</font>
        </li>
     
    </ul>
    <br><br>
    <font color="white">
        <center>
            Disclaimer: Please note that this is to help us support the server costs. Donating to ARKinator is greatly appreciated however once donated. Non-refundable purchase.
        </center>
            </font>
       
    <br><br>
    <center><button class="button"><span><a href="paypal.me/gamingasylum038" style="text-decoration:none">PayPal</a></span></button></center>
 
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar" style="color:white;">
    Copyright 2018 © ARKinator | All Rights Reserved.
  </div>
</body>
```